# Finding relationships in the rdf for SparQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I've just started working with SparQL end point of a service called MyExperiment.
and I'm totally new to the semantic web.

The service endpoint url is this : http://rdf.myexperiment.org/sparql

Basically I've figured out how to do basic queries. Like listing some objects forexample workflows by the query below :

```
BASE <http://www.myexperiment.org/> 
PREFIX myexp: <http://www.myexperiment.org/> 
PREFIX mecontrib: <http://rdf.myexperiment.org/ontologies/contributions/> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?workflow WHERE { ?workflow rdf:type mecontrib:Workflow}
```

I have two questions.

1. I need to find the relationships between the different concepts in RDFs. like I know there is a concept called "Workflow" in a RDF, and there is a concept called "User" in another RDF, how can I find the relationship between these two?
2. How can I create a query to mix two or more concepts. Like I want to see the list of workflows with the user name created them or find workflows created by a User?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparql query's WHERE-clause is a graph pattern consisting of one or several triplets connected via variables or blank nodes (if value is not used/not important). This graph is checked against triplet store with attempt to bind used variables and thus return result set.

Think of WHERE-clause as a set of triplet subject-predicate-object statements which need to be fulfilled for particular instances to appear in result set.

Concerning your 1st question. This is task of finding path in graph. If both concepts belong to single or to related (e.g. referred) well-formed ontologies, some hints can be given by playing around with query like this (taking your provided example as a base):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?prop, ?range WHERE { ?workflow a mecontrib:Workflow .
                                       ?workflow ?prop ?value .
                                       ?prop rdfs:range ?range }
```

In it we ask to list all available distinct predicates (which may be treated as properties) of Workflow concept with its range. Range defines type of property values (See [OWL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#range-def)). By comparing range to needed type one can find property which relates two concepts one to another. However, this axiom is not always defined but when it is it can be used in simplest case to check whether some concept has property which relates it to another concept.
Also, [property pathes](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/) can be used for tracking pathes of arbitrary length but this is still work-in-progress and may be not supported by all rdf storages (See [link](http://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Feature%3aPropertyPaths)).

So, the easiest way seems to analyse ontologies you're working on to find answer for particular case rather then attempt to find general solution.

Concerning 2nd question. Just use several triplet patterns in WHERE-clause. Consider following example:

```
SELECT ?book, ?authorName FROM <http://myrdfgraph>
WHERE { ?book a Book .
        ?book hasAuthor ?author
        ?author hasName ?authorName }
```

We're asking imaginary graph based on library ontology which contains concept Book with property hasName. Range of hasAuthor is instance of Author concept. And Author concept has property hasName denoting name of novelist. Such query will return list of all Books with names of writers. Hope this will help you to apply example in your case.

Also, consider learning from [SPARQL specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query).

Answer (score 1):

The SPARQL query to get all relations into the RDF graph is:

```
SELECT ?domain ?property ?range
WHERE{  
       ?property rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
       ?property rdfs:range ?range .
       ?property rdfs:domain ?domain
     }
```